# Spring webflow, transist only if statement is true

Tags: java, jsf, spring-webflow

I want my flow to transist only if some statement is true, otherwise it should stay at the same page (in the same view-state). My problem is that if I use decision-state without else clause I will stay in that decision-state, so if I use again previous action it won't be recognized. I could use redirection to previous view-state but it makes my view reloading.

Some example:

```
<view-state id="myState" view=someView.xhtml">
  <transition on="myAction" to="decision"/>
</view-state>

<decision-state id="myDecision">
  <if test="controller.isOk()" then="nextPage"/>
</decision-state>
```

1. In myState I execute myAction
2. myDecision invokes 'controller.isOk()'
3. Result is false, so I'm not redirected anywhere
4. I execute one again myAction but there is no transition for 'myAction'

I also tried action-state but I don't want to define transition for 'no' case and it generates errors.

Comment: Is this question related to JSF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [put calls inside `<evaluate>` inside a `<transition>`, and if the call doesn't return "success", which is "success", "yes", or "true", the flow will remain on the same state](https://docs.spring.io/spring-webflow/docs/2.4.7.RELEASE/reference/html/views.html#transition-actions).

So try this:

```xml
<view-state id="myState" view="someView.xhtml">
    <transition on="myAction" to="nextPage>
        <evaluate expression="controller.isOk()"/>
    </transition>
</view-state>
```